# Edit a really short question

Tags: discussion, edits

I was doing a few review and saw this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462060/arduino-with-bluetooth-module

The question is really short so I'll quote the entire text here:

> Can someone please explain me the meaning of this piece of code
>   SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5) in arduino programming language please?

At first I didn't understand it because I saw no code, so I though that it should be edited to look like:

> Can someone please explain me the meaning of this piece of code
>
> ```
> SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5)
> ```
>
> in arduino programming language please?

But SO doesn't allow me to post my edit because it is shorter than 6 char (apparently, spaces and backspaces don't count since I added some).

What should I do in this case?

- Leave the question like this?
- Write a comment to ask for formatting?
- Downvote (too short and badly formatted)?
- Other?

Comment: There was definitely more that could've been done with that edit: _"Can someone please explain me"_ for example is not proper English grammar. The second part of the sentence is also awkward. You could've fixed the grammar as well and likely would've had enough to make your edit go through.

Comment: You are right, maybe I didn't spend enough time on it, my idea was to quickly edit what stunt me when reading the question. But if I phrase it differently, why is it a bad idea to edit less than 6 characters?

Comment: The idea behind the 6 character limit is that your edit has to be reviewed. Since it has to be reviewed, the team doesn't want us making trivial, one-character typo fixes. The thought there is that those edits would be wasting the time of the reviewers. (And you can usually find more than a couple characters to fix if you're really trying.) Once you get past 2k rep and have full editing privileges, that limit goes away. (You're also correct that whitespace doesn't count toward the character limit.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the amont of trivial changes that would be reviewed otherwise (should have think about it). Could you copy your two comments into an answer to my question?

Comment: The question is really bad and needs to just be closed. Don't waste time editing it until there is enough there for a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Like Kendra [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323856/edit-a-really-short-question#comment348767_323856), you should reword things. Please also remove the "please", which is noise please. Please.

Personally, I would just rewrite the entire question.

> <s>Can someone please explain me the meaning of this piece of code</s> `In Arduino programming, what does this code mean?`
>
> SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5)
>
> <s>in arduino programming language please?</s>

I moved all the words above the code because it's more likely to show up in the excerpt (the blurb you see on the front pages or new question list). I don't know the exact algorithm, but it will sometimes cut off when it sees code.